# Ruby and Nil Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a webapp (well trying to) in Ruby on Rails.

I have a partial render in my index.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "houses/index", :locals => @houses %>
```

index.html.erb is loaded when the user hits the root of my domain. This partial cause this error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

Extracted Source around line 8

```
5:     <th>Washrooms</th>
6:   </tr>
7: 
8: <% @houses.each do |house| %>
9:   <tr>
10:     <td><%=h house.short_desc %></td>
11:     <td><%=h house.bedrooms %></td>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/home/index.html.erb

All I would like to is display 5 houses on my Homepage (index.html.erb)

What am I missing to get this to work?

Many thanks

EDIT:

[Houses_controller](http://pastebin.ca/1666849)

NoMethodError in Home#index

Showing app/views/houses/_index.html.erb where line #10 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Extracted source (around line #10):

7:     Washrooms
8:   
9: 
10: <% @houses.each do |house| %>
11:   
12:     <%=h house.short_desc %>
13:     <%=h house.bedrooms %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/home/index.html.erb

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but wouldnt :collection => @houses be more appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of :locals is supposed to be a Hash that defines local variables. So

```
<%= render :partial => "houses/index", :locals => {:houses => @houses} %>
```

and then

```
<% houses.each do |house| %>
```

To reiterate, since the new error you posted shows that you are still not doing it correctly:

If you're passing it through `:locals`, you want `houses.each`, not **@**houses.each. No snail. Local variables don't have a `@` prefix; instance variables do.

Answer (score 2):

Locals takes a hash of local variables, like so:

```
<%= render :partial => "houses/index", :locals => { :houses => @houses } %>
```

Also, when you pass in a local variable to a partial, you should use it as a local variable rather than an instance variable within the partial, as so:

```
<% houses.each do |house| %>
# do stuff with each house
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is returning the same error? Do I want to place the above code in my app/views/home/index.html.erb? Thanks again

Comment: @Crankyadmin: It's a replacement for the code you posted above. **Is** `@houses` set to anything meaningful in your controller?

Comment: I have added more information. _index.html.erb exists. I have linked to my houses controller. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass it in `:locals` if it's an instance variable. Instance variables are available in all partials.

In your view:

```
<% @houses.each do |house| %>
  # do stuff with each house
<% end %>
```